# Use of the word maximum in the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar

If we want to say that the maximum value of a thing is '4 dollars' or any other value can we put it this way, 'This car might cost you 35000 dollars to the maximum'?

Comment: If the maximum is known, might is *usually* not a good fit. "This car will cost you 35k dollars max(imum)", "This car will cost you a maximum of 35k$", "This car will cost you 35,000$, at most", "This car will cost you at most 35,000 dollars."

Comment: Far more idiomatic (in the US, at least) would be "This car might cost you 35000 dollars max."

Answer (score -1):

"to the maximum" isn't good English - the informal phrase "to the max!" has entered the language but you shouldn't try to expand it back out again.  You could say *"The car will cost you a maximum of $35,000"*, or, if you wanted to hedge your bets a bit, you could say "The car ***should*** cost you a maximum of $35,000", implying that if you see it for a higher price then the seller is trying to rip you off.

Just to expand on @MorganFR's comment:  "might" is redundant because the use of the word "maximum" already implies that there is some **uncertainty**, so "might" doesn't add any extra information.

That doesn't stop people using redundant language in terms like this:  I've often seen "up to" used with "maximum", even though they mean the same thing, e.g.

> "This might cost you up to a maximum of $1000".

This is just bad writing.

Comment: Yes, "up to a maximum of" sounds really wrong. "up to 35k" on it's own is good though.

Comment: Yes, i think "Up to $35k" is nicer-sounding than "a maximum of $35k".

Comment: It's not uncommon to hear (in the US) *This car might cost you 35000 dollars, maximum* or *This car might cost you 35000 dollars max.* Informal usage.

Comment: @bib yes, redundant language is everywhere.

Comment: 'This car will cost you 35K to the max' would do? @MaxWilliams

Comment: @Eva Not "***to*** the max" - "***at*** the max".

Comment: *'This car will cost you 35K at the max'* sounds odd to me - i don't think people would tend to say that.  It would be more common to write *'This car will cost you 35K, max'*, if you're determined to have "max" at the end that is.